# How to set up a view for preview the image after you selected it in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create a view to preview the image after you selected one in the UIImagePickerController. I have tried to create a view controller and push the picker controller to another view controller.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ImagePreviewController *ipc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePreviewController"];
    UIImage * image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    ipc.selectedImage = image;
    [picker pushViewController:ipc animated:YES];
 }
```

As you can see I have tried to push the UIImagePickerController to another view and tries to preview it. But unfortunately the ipc object shows null when I debug it. I understands that the UIImagePickerController is inherited from the UINavigationController. Is it because in this navigation controller it can't find the view of my ipc? If yes, how can I add it into the UIImagePickerController so it can push to the preview image view? If not, how can I set up a preview image view properly?

Update: If I put

```
    ImagePreviewController *ipc = [ImagePreviewController alloc]init];
```

instead, when it pushes, it's a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dismiss the image picker and then present your custom `UIViewController` subclass

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIViewController *presentingViewController = picker.presentingViewController;
    ImagePreviewController *ipc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePreviewController"];
    UIImage * image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    ipc.selectedImage = image;

    [presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(BOOL animated){
        [presentingViewController presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
 }
```

Comment: The ipc shows it's nil but I'm 101% sure it's right there.

Comment: And also I have tried your code but unfortunately the screen is still black.

Comment: Turns out it's some mistake of my ImagePreviewController class. Your code is fine. Thanks for the help.